# Registration PCL + kinect

Tags: c++, kinect, registration, point-cloud-library, point-clouds

I'm doing degree work on 3D Mapping through the Kinect v1 and PCL.
I'm doing the 'Registration' of two point clouds with this code: https://github.com/PointCloudLibrary/pcl/blob/master/doc/tutorials/content/sources/registration_api/example1.cpp

When executing this code I get this error:

> kdtree_flann.hpp: 136: int pcl :: KdTreeFLANN  ::
>   closestKSearch (const PointT &, int, std :: vector  &, std ::
>   vector  &) const [with PointT = pcl :: PointNormal; Dist =
>   flann :: L2_Simple ]: Affirmation `point_representation _->
>   isValid (point) &&" The coordinates of the invalid points (NaN, Inf)
>   given to the nearest HOT search "" have failed. Aborted (`core
>   'generated)

How can I fix this error?

Comment: i don't have a kinect or use this codebase but it seems that some of the points you have provided to the program have coordinates that are invalid (NaN and Inf values). maybe make sure the source.pcd file you are providing has proper points?

Comment: you can use pcl::removeNaNFromPointCloud (http://docs.pointclouds.org/trunk/group__filters.html#gac463283a9e9c18a66d3d29b28a575064)